# Way to remove custom style with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I can add custom style using NamedStyle from openpyxl.
Is there any way to get existing custom styles and remove using openpyxl?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well so I hacked until this worked.   I used the _named_styles , which isn't exactly best practice, but it gets the job done.

I used list comp returning index from an index value lookup

```
del wb._named_styles[ wb.style_names.index('yourstyle')]
```

I put this additional check to make certain its present before deleting

```
if a_style in wb.named_styles:
        del wb._named_styles[ wb.style_names.index(a_style)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi it seems like you can use `workbook.named_styles` to get style list.
This will return a list including all style exist.